# Flutter firebase_auth package android build error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.auth.TotpSecret

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

After upgrade to latest versions of firebase packages for flutter I get this error when building apk for android:

```
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.15.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseTotpSecret.java:11: error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.auth.TotpSecret; 

symbol: class TotpSecret

 location: package com.google.firebase.auth 

.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.15.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseTotpMultiFactor.java:11: error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.auth.TotpMultiFactorAssertion; 

symbol: class TotpMultiFactorAssertion 

location: package com.google.firebase.auth 

.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.15.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseTotpMultiFactor.java:12: error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.auth.TotpMultiFactorGenerator; 

symbol: class TotpMultiFactorGenerator 

location: package com.google.firebase.auth 

.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.15.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseTotpMultiFactor.java:13: error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.auth.TotpSecret; 

symbol: class TotpSecret 

location: package com.google.firebase.auth 

.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.15.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseTotpMultiFactor.java:22: error: cannot find symbol static final Map<String, TotpSecret> multiFactorSecret = new HashMap<>(); 
symbol: class TotpSecret 
location: class FlutterFirebaseTotpMultiFactor
```

**Pubspec.yaml:**

```
dependencies: 

firebase_messaging: ^14.7.9

firebase_auth: ^4.15.3 

firebase_core: ^2.24.2
```

**Gradle wrapper:** gradle-8.5-all.zip

**Gradle.build**:

```
dependencies { 

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0' 

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0' 
}
```

**Java:** openjdk-17.jdk

Build for iOS works fine. Latest version for android that could build without issue was with dependencies:

- firebase_messaging: 14.6.0
- firebase_auth: 4.7.3
- firebase_core: 2.15.1

I found this reported issue https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11648 but they don't say how to fix it, only that issue is resolved.

Any suggestions?